# SwiftUI 2 Observable objects in one view which depend on each other

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Thanks for all the support I have received, I trying to build an macos app that tags pdfs for machine learning purposes. I have followed Stanford SwiftUI course, and I want to create main view for my app that contains the document and to type a regex string to find in the document. The deal is I need to create a document chooser, to add documents to be analized, but I don't know how to deal with 2 view models in the same view. In fact one of those view models depend on the other one. The solution I found (not a solution a messy workaround) is to initialize the document manager as a separate view and use it as a navigation view, with a navigation link, but the look is horrible. I'll paste the code and explain it better.

This is the stores view

```
struct PDFTaggerDocumentStoreView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var store:PDFTaggerDocumentStore
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Spacer()
                Text("Document Store").fontWeight(.heavy)
                Button(action: {self.store.addDocument()}, label: {Text("Add document")})
                Divider()
                ForEach(store.documents){ doc in
                    NavigationLink(destination: PDFTaggerMainView(pdfTaggerDocument: doc)) {
                        Text(self.store.name(for: doc))
                    }
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    indexSet.map{self.store.documents[$0]}.forEach { (document) in
                        self.store.removeDocuments(document)
                    }
                }
            }
                        
        }
        
    }
}
```

The main view.

```
struct PDFTaggerDocumentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var document:PDFTaggerDocument
    @State private var expression = ""
    @State private var regexField = ""
    @State private var showExpressionEditor = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 0.5)
                    .frame(width: 600)
                    .padding()
                VStack {
                    Text("Try expression ")
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Type regex", text: $document.regexString)
                            .frame(width: 200)
                        Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: "icons8-save-80")!)
                            .scaleEffect(0.3)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.showExpressionEditor = true
                                print(self.document.regexString)
                                print(self.regexField)
                        }
                        .popover(isPresented: $showExpressionEditor) {
                            ExpressionEditor().environmentObject(self.document)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    Picker(selection: $expression, label: EmptyView()) {
                        ForEach(document.expressionNames.sorted(by: >), id:\.key) { key, value in
                            Text(key)
                        }
                    }
                    Button(action: self.addToDocument, label: {Text("Add to document")})
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 200)
                }
                .frame(width:600)
                .padding()
            }
            .padding()
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white).overlay(OptionalPDFView(pdfDocument: document.backgroundPDF))
                .frame(width:600, height:500)
                .onDrop(of: ["public.file-url"], isTargeted: nil) { (providers, location) -> Bool in
                    let result = providers.first?.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.file-url")
                    providers.first?.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.file-url") { data, error in
                        if let safeData = data {
                            let newURL = URL(dataRepresentation: safeData, relativeTo: nil)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.document.backgroundURL = newURL
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return result!
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd like to be able to initialize both views models in the same view, and make the document view, be dependent on the document chooser model.

Is there a way I can do it?

Thanks a lot for your time.